# How to resize a file, "trimming" its beginning?

Tags: c#, file, filesystems, queue

I am implementing a file-based queue of serialized objects, using C#.

- `Push()` will serialize an object as binary and append it to the end of the file.
- `Pop()` should deserialize an object from the beginning of the file (this part I got working). Then, the deserialized part should be removed from the file, making the next object to be "first".

From the standpoint of file system, that would just mean copying file header several bytes further on the disk, and then moving the "beginning of the file" pointer. The question is how to implement this in C#? Is it at all possible?

Comment: I assume you're storing your own "record header" information.. yes?

Comment: @Simon the binary serializer does it

Comment: @Shedal you should [take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430210/insert-bytes-into-middle-of-a-file-in-windows-filesystem-without-reading-entir), from couple weeks ago - if I'm not mistaking what you're after. What you want is not easy, from C# point of view (handling file-system low-level requires a filter driver, a bit oversimplified but true in most cases). So, I'd say no its not, that way. But you could try to 'virtualize' it in some way - e.g. move the pointer (seek) yourself - and then perform periodical `trimming` of the file - by resaving it.

Comment: @NSGaga thanks for the link. So it seems there is no easy way to do what I want. Hence, I'll have to go another way. Probably, just creating a new file for each serialized object.

Comment: If that's what you really wanted I guess no (i.e. moving the file headers, pointers around). Yes, I'd recommend you re-access - it's usually not a good idea making your 'own database format' like that. You could use XML (and mix data) - or use 'file system' as you suggested - or something in between. E.g. cache in bigger files, but some optiomal # of 'records'. There're many possibilities - I guess it depends on exactly the 'usage' goal is (how much records, is it 'one-time' or reusing etc.). If you describe a bit more I may post an answer which is more meaningful.

Comment: We log lots of information about site visits into the database. For the case when the "log database" server is down, we need to buffer visit data somewhere. The simplest is to use the file system. Initially I wanted to use one file, and, when the log database goes up, start popping items from the beginning of the file, thus, pushing the visits to the DB in the same order they actually happened. As this process might take a while, I also wanted to clean up the disk space ASAP, removing the deserialized data from the file.

Comment: @Shedal I'm a bit slow on response :), busy - I just posted sort of an 'answer', hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest that I can see

1) stream out (like a log, dump it into file),
(note: you'd need some delimiters and a 'consistent format' of your 'file' - based on what your data is)

2) and later stream in (just read file from start, in one go, and process w/o removing anything)

and that'd work fine, FIFO (first in first out).

> So, my suggestion - don't try to optimize that by removing, skipping
>   etc. (rather regroup and use more files.

3) If you worry about the scale of things - then just 'partition' that into small enough files, e.g. each 100 or 1,000 `records` (depends, do some calculations).

You may need to make some sort of 'virtualizer' here, which maps files, keeps track of your 'database' as, if it's over multiple files. The simplest is to just use the file-system and check file times etc. Or add some basic code to improve that.

> However, I think you may have problems if you have to ensure
>   '**transactions**' - i.e. what if things fail so you need to keep track of
>   where the file left off, retrace etc.

That might be an issue, but you know best if it's really necessary to have that (how critical). You can always work 'per file' and per smaller files. If it fails, rollback and do the file again (or log problems). If it succeeds you can delete file (after success) and go on like that.

This is very 'hand made' approach but should get you going with a simple and not too demanding solution (like you're describing). Or something along those lines.

**I should probably add**...

You could also save you some trouble and use some portable database for that or something similar. This is was purely based on the idea of hand-coding a simplest solution (and we could probably come up with something smarter, but being late this is what I have :).

Answer (score 1):

Files don't work that way. You can trim off the end, but not the beginning. In order to mutate a file to remove content at the beginning you need to re-write the entire file.

I expect you'll want to find some other way to solve your problem. But a linear file is totally inappropriate for representing a FIFO queue.